# Deck with hatch to access storage area - thoughts on hatch design

Tags: deck

I am doing a free standing deck.  ~20'x14'.  Current design is 3 beams (3 member 2x12s @ 20') and 2x6 12"oc joists that span 7' between the beams.  3' of cantilever on each side of the end posts.

Footings with be 10" thick 3'x3' with a 6" concrete column.  Bottom of footings will be 18" below surrounding grade.

There will be approximately 4' of height from the bottom of the beams to the ground, slightly more under the 2x6s.  I am going to put 5/8" ply on the surface and a torch on membrane followed by loose lay composite.

The idea behind the torch on is the membrane is good for > 30 years and the area under the deck would be dry.  I'd slope the deck surface 2% away from the house for drainage at the torch on layer.  Composite on top of it would be for aesthetics.  The grade is only 2' below the sides of the deck so I don't want a 1' crawl way or to have a recessed access point so I am thinking the hatch is the best plan to access the storage.

There is a basement with walls that are 4' below the deck storage area. There are pdrains around the foundation with a powered sump system. I'd plan to slope the ground under it 2% away from foundation and install a perforated drain on the edges of the storage depression that lead to a gravel well that leads to the perimeter drain. At the depression depth I'd be below the rain drain level.  The grade is fairly level outside the deck structure.  I'll put landscape fabric overtop the dirt and then a 2" layer of river rock.

The hatch will be a hole in the member and will allow some water to go into the storage space.  My thoughts are either I have the hatch closest to the house at the high area that also has a bit of an overhang and might get more overhang later when I swap the single door for a slider or I put it at the bottom of the 2% slope farthest from the house but where the water hitting the gravel would more quickly get to the depression perimeter drain.

How big should I make my hatch?  Any thoughts on design?  Ideally it would blend in with the surface of the deck and not be super noticeable.  Since I'd want the hatch to be walked on would I put joist hangers on the beams and have removeable 2x6s that support the hatch?  Or maybe go with a piece of steel for the hatch.

Quick structural sketch of the deck.[image]

Comment: Size depends on what you want to store in there more than anything else. Where does water from the house roof drain? Likewise, if it's 2 feet around the edges and 4 feet in the middle, where else can water run downhill from? (*i.e.* may be less dry under there than you hope, depending.) If I understand your description correctly, short chunks of composite decking that overlay the hatch but which are cut so they don't outline it would be the least obvious top treatment; under that I'd consider a fairly standard trap door treatment.

Comment: Thanks I've added water management details to my post.  I've never done a trap door maybe I just need to research the best practice for that.

Comment: You are making a water proof deck and then putting a large hole in it. What about how to  make the hatch/opening water proof ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan Thanks added details on hatch location based on water issue with it.